# why did my ceramic matrix composite turn out brittle as snow?

Tags: materials, manufacturing-engineering, material-science, composite, ceramics

I have attempted making a ceramic matrix composite (cmc) by wetting glass fiber cloth with waterglass and baking it at 200°C. The resulting material disintegrated on touch. Unwetted fibers did not change their properties after baking.

How can this be explained?

Did suction caused by evaporation of water pulled apart pieces of sodium silicate attached to fibers, ultimately pulling apart cracks on the fiber surface?

Shouldn't glass fiber surfaces be "crackless"?